# How to split json array from ajax GET into objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Good night everyone.

I've seen this question answered in other posts, but no answer works for me, I'm new in ajax/json and I'm a bit lost.
I have this ajax call that returns me a JSON array:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: common.RestURL.index,
            dataType: 'json'

        }).done(parameters => {
            //Fill parameters
            drawSettings(parameters);

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            showMsg(jqXHR.responseJSON.message,
                "Error",
                "error");
        });
```

This is the exact json object to return:

```
"config": [
{
  "configDescription": "description1",
  "configValue": "value1",
  "configKey": "key1",
  "idCompany": "company1",
  "appConfigurationId": "config1",
  "configType": "List"
},
{
  "configDescription": "description2",
  "configValue": "value2",
  "configKey": "key2",
  "idCompany": "company2",
  "appConfigurationId": "config2",
  "configType": "Date"
},
{
  "configDescription": "description3",
  "configValue": "value3",
  "configKey": "key3",
  "idCompany": "company3",
  "appConfigurationId": "config3",
  "configType": "String"
},
{
  "configDescription": "description4",
  "configValue": "value4",
  "configKey": "key4",
  "idCompany": "company4",
  "appConfigurationId": "config4",
  "configType": "Boolean"
}]
```

So when the ajax call gets the json array, it calls another method that works with each of the objects in the array, but when I try to create each object, they are created empty and I can't find the problem, this is the function I'm talking about:

```
function drawSettings(parameters) {

    if (!$.isArray(parameters)) {
        parameters = [parameters];
    }

    //Fill params in div
    $.each(parameters, function (key, value) {

        //Parameter to draw
        console.log("value .........................." + value.configDescription);
        let param = new Parameter(value);
        console.log("objetooo ------------ " + param.configDescription);
```

The Parameter class is a simple class with the attributes of the json ojects and the logs show the attributes with "undefined" value.
Can please someone help me understand and solve the problem?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: In your Ajax callback: `drawSettings(parameters)` should probably be `drawSettings(parameters.config)`, if you only want the Array

Comment: When I pass the parameters like this and make a console.log() on the drawSettings function it returns "Undefined"

Comment: but this actually solved my problem, it should be parameters.data, that's the array, so you gave me the solution or at least the main clue, thank you so so much!

Comment: The Object you showed us had a `config` property containing the Array, that's why I said that :) Glad it solved your problem!